# Вопрос по Navigation Drawer

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, android

Добрый день,

Просматривая  официальный документы на Android, наткнулся на интересную [статью](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Content)

В самом низу есть картинка, где в Navigation Drawer включен Spinner(?), который открывает подменю.

Поделитесь ссылкой, где разобран подобный пример или приведен похожий код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

мне кажется там изображён ExpandableListView, хотя никто не мешает вам использовать  Spinner,  Navigation Drawer по сути своей фрагмент, технически можете туда писать все что хотите

Comment: Спасибо, вы натолкнули на отличную идею